# Log file is not generated after running JAR

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have `logback.xml` file saved in `src/main/resources` of my Maven project. The path where the log file should be saved is defined as follows: `file>/my/path/myLog.log</file>`.

I package the JAR file using IntelliJ IDEA. When I run this JAR file, `myLog.log` does not appear in `/my/path/`.

The problem is that everything works file if I convert my project to SBT and use sbt assembly. In this case the logs are saved. But in case of packaging the project with Maven, I do not see my logs.

The `pom.xml` is specified as follows:

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-a</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>org.my.Test</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <finalName>myTest</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assembly</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Configure maven-compiler-plugin to use the desired Java version -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Use build-helper-maven-plugin to add Scala source and test source directories -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/scala</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/test/scala</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Use scala-maven-plugin for Scala support -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```